# php move_uploaded_file()

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

So I'm testing out the move_uploaded_file() php script from the w3schools website http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp.
Here is my code.

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
{
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    else
    {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

        if (file_exists("/var/www/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
        {
          echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }
        elseif(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/var/www/upload/".$fileName))
            echo "Stored in: " . "/var/www/upload/".$fileName;
    }
}
else
    echo "Invalid file";
```

The problem is `if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"/var/www/upload/".$fileName))` returns false all the time but it seems the file is stored in the `tmp` folder on the server (for example: `/tmp/php8rrKoW`). When I check the `tmp` folder the file is not there. (It's supposed to get deleted after the script finish executing.) I also don't see the `/php8rrkoW` folder. I'm not sure if it's supposed to be there. I set the permission for both the `tmp` folder and `/var/www/upload/` to `777` using `chmod`, but I'm not sure if I should set the owner to `apache`. So I want to know why the file isn't copied over to `/var/www/upload` and if there is a way to test this.

Comment: Have you enabled error_reporting(E_ALL) and what errors are you getting?

Comment: Try to request `index.php` with `<?php
file_put_contents('/var/www/upload/test.txt', 'test');`. Do you see any error and is the file created successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic image upload class I made for another question the other day, simple to use, perhaps your find it interesting.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); //Will help you debug a [server/path/permission] issue
Class uploadHandler{
    public $upload_path;
    public $full_path;
    public $name;
    public $size;
    public $ext;
    public $output;
    public $input;
    public $prefix;
    private $allowed;

    function upload(){
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
            if(isset($_FILES[$this->input]['error'])){
                if($_FILES[$this->input]['error'] == 0){
                    $this->name      = basename($_FILES[$this->input]['name']);
                    $file_p          = explode('.', $this->name);
                    $this->ext       = end($file_p);
                    $this->full_path = rtrim($this->upload_path,'/').'/'.preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]/s', '_', $this->prefix.'_'.$file_p[0]).'.'.$this->ext;
                    $info            = getimagesize($_FILES[$this->input]['tmp_name']);
                    $this->size      = filesize($_FILES[$this->input]['tmp_name']);

                    if($info[0]>$this->allowed['dimensions']['width'] || $info[1] > $this->allowed['dimensions']['height']){
                        $this->output = 'File dimensions too large!';
                    }else{
                        if($info[0] > 0 && $info[1] > 0 && in_array($info['mime'],$this->allowed['types'])){
                            move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$this->input]['tmp_name'],$this->full_path);
                            $this->output = 'Upload success!';
                        }else{
                            $this->output = 'File not supported!';
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if($_FILES[$this->input]['error']==1){$this->output = 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive!';}
                    if($_FILES[$this->input]['error']==2){$this->output = 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in our HTML form!';}
                    if($_FILES[$this->input]['error']==3){$this->output = 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded!';}
                    if($_FILES[$this->input]['error']==4){$this->output = 'No file was uploaded!';}
                    if($_FILES[$this->input]['error']==6){$this->output = 'Missing a temporary folder!';}
                    if($_FILES[$this->input]['error']==7){$this->output = 'Failed to write uploaded file to disk!';}
                    if($_FILES[$this->input]['error']==8){$this->output = 'A PHP extension stopped the file upload!';}
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function setPath($var){
        $this->upload_path = $var;
    }
    function setAllowed($var=array()){
        $this->allowed = $var;
    }
    function setFilePrefix($var){
        $this->prefix = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]/s', '_', $var);
    }
    function setInput($var){
        $this->input = $var;
    }

}



//Start class
$upload = new uploadHandler();
//Set path
$upload->setPath('./');
//Prefix the file name
$upload->setFilePrefix('user_uploads');
//Allowed types
$upload->setAllowed(array('dimensions'=>array('width'=>200,'height'=>200),
                          'types'=>array('image/png','image/jpg','image/gif')));
//form property name                   
$upload->setInput('myfile');
//Do upload
$upload->upload();


//notice
if(isset($upload->output)){
    echo $upload->output;
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <!--1 MB = 1048576 bytes-->
     <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1048000" />

     <p>Upload your image:<input type="file" name="myfile"><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>

</form>
```

Comment: I got 'Upload success' message but I cant find the uploaded file. In which location this file will be stored? I have deployed code in /var/www/html/test/index.php.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should be using ./upload/ instead of /var/www/upload/ since you are already in the main directory of the accessible website.

You can also refer to http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php 
or the API : http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Let me know if that works

Comment: I tried the code from tizag and changed it to ./upload but I got "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!". I'm not sure if the file is transfered to the temp folder.

Answer (score 0):

The destination directory you want to move the files into should be writable by the webserver user. Also don't forget that some webservers operate inside a changeroot, so parts of the destination path may not be needed. The PHP help doc also says you should check the HTLM form to ensure it's enctype='multipart/form-data'.

And finally: where is $filename defined?

Answer (score 0):

Your path must consist of '/home/usr-name'

Try adding '/home/your-username' to the beginning of '/var/www/upload' .

To get an idea, add a info.php into your root directory, open it up in a browser and look under 'Loaded Configuration File'.