# Php OOps file upload working script

Tags: php, file, upload

This is a script I got from devshed. It works great in Opera and others (not in IE). My question is: how does this script works without `$_FILES['userfile']['name'] & $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']`?

```
<?php
    class FileUploader
    {
    private $uploadFile;
    private $name;
    private $tmp_name;
    private $type;
    private $size;
    private $error;
    private $allowedTypes=array
    ('image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png','text/plain','application/ms-word');

    public function __construct($uploadDir="./uploadfl/")
    {
    if(!is_dir($uploadDir)){
    throw new Exception('Invalid upload directory.');
    }

    if(!count($_FILES))
    {
    throw new Exception('Invalid number of file upload parameters.');
    }

    foreach($_FILES['userfile'] as $key=>$value)
    {
    $this->{$key}=$value;
    }

    if(!in_array($this->type,$this->allowedTypes))
    {
    throw new Exception('Invalid MIME type of target file.');
    }

    $this->uploadFile=$uploadDir.basename($this->name); 

    }
    // upload target file to specified location

    public function upload(){
    if(move_uploaded_file($this->tmp_name,$this->uploadFile)){
    return true;
    }


    }
    }
    ?>

    <?php
      if($_POST['send']){
    //require_once 'fileuploader.php';
    $fileUploader=new FileUploader();
    if($fileUploader->upload()){
    echo 'Target file uploaded successfully!';
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: did you mention `enctype` in form `enctype= multipart/form-data`

Comment: yeah all that's okay ...this script works.. only wondering ---   without $_FILEs['userfile']['name'] & $_FILEs['userfile']['tmp_name'] this part..iam new to oops so

Comment: @jathin check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291655/php-move-uploaded-file/10291918#10291918 Much more cleaner n secure and dont throw exceptions, returns nice error messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question (How this script works without $_FILEs['userfile']['name'] & $_FILEs['userfile']['tmp_name']):
It does work without it because the array keys are assigned as properties here:

```
$this->{$key}=$value;
```

So instead of $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] it can now be referred to as

```
$this->tmp_name
```

You've already got a reply as to why it might not work in all browsers.

Hope that helps,
Stefan

Comment: thanks mate...Yup...i'm surprised by the quick response here  on stackoverflow.Thanks every body.